# Issue with not able to paint with selected color in android

Tags: java, android

In this program the issue is that the selected color is not used for drawing subsequently.
Please, can anyone check my switch statement in MainActivity.java and PaintView where I have written code to setup the color.

MainActivity

```
package com.easyway2win;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Button butnViolet,butnBlue,butnDGreen,butnRed,butnYellow;
    private Button squareBtn, circleBtn;
    private PaintView paintView; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        butnViolet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cviolet);
        butnBlue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cblue);
        butnDGreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cgreen);
        butnRed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cred);
        butnYellow =(Button)findViewById(R.id.cyellow); 
        squareBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSquare);
        //View paintView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        //paintView = (PaintView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        circleBtn=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCircle);
        paintView = new PaintView(getBaseContext());
    }

    public void clickMe(View view){

        int intColor = 0, intShape = 0;
        String hexColor = null;

        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.cviolet:
            intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.violet);

                    // Integer.toHexString(color).toUpperCase();//upercase with alpha
            hexColor = Integer.toHexString(intColor).toUpperCase().substring(2);// uppercase without alpha
            Log.d("Hi", "I am color ");
            break;
        case R.id.cblue:
            intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
            Log.d("Hi", "I am Blue color " + intColor);
            break;
        case R.id.cgreen:
            intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.redsugar);
            Log.d("Hi", "I am Green color " + intColor);

            break;
        case R.id.cred:
            intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
            Log.d("Hi", "I am Red color " + intColor);
            break;
        case R.id.cyellow:
            intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
            Log.d("Hi", "I am yellow color " + intColor);
            break;
        case R.id.btnSquare:

             intShape = 1;
             Log.d("Hi", "I am square shape ");
             break;
        }

        paintView.setPaintColour(hexColor);

        Log.i("Hi.............","...." + hexColor);
        //paintView.setSelectedShape(intShape);

    }
}

       PaintView

          package com.easyway2win;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Display;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity{

            private Button butnViolet,butnBlue,butnDGreen,butnRed,butnYellow;
            private Button squareBtn, circleBtn;
            private PaintView paintView; 

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                butnViolet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cviolet);
                butnBlue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cblue);
                butnDGreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cgreen);
                butnRed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cred);
                butnYellow =(Button)findViewById(R.id.cyellow); 
                squareBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSquare);
                //View paintView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
                //paintView = (PaintView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
                circleBtn=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCircle);
                paintView = new PaintView(getBaseContext());
            }

            public void clickMe(View view){

                int intColor = 0, intShape = 0;
                String hexColor = null;

                switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.cviolet:
                    intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.violet);

                            // Integer.toHexString(color).toUpperCase();//upercase with alpha
                    hexColor = Integer.toHexString(intColor).toUpperCase().substring(2);// uppercase without alpha
                    Log.d("Hi", "I am color ");
                    break;
                case R.id.cblue:
                    intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                    Log.d("Hi", "I am Blue color " + intColor);
                    break;
                case R.id.cgreen:
                    intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.redsugar);
                    Log.d("Hi", "I am Green color " + intColor);

                    break;
                case R.id.cred:
                    intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                    Log.d("Hi", "I am Red color " + intColor);
                    break;
                case R.id.cyellow:
                    intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                    Log.d("Hi", "I am yellow color " + intColor);
                    break;
                case R.id.btnSquare:

                     intShape = 1;
                     Log.d("Hi", "I am square shape ");
                     break;
                }

                paintView.setPaintColour(hexColor);

                Log.i("Hi.............","...." + hexColor);
                //paintView.setSelectedShape(intShape); 
            }

        }
```

Comment: clearer, spelling, formatting, tag

Comment: You are not calculating `hexColor` for each case statement. You can move `intColor` to `hexColor` conversion outside and after of switch block.